# Create a Calculated Field with multiple condition in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on Tableau Desktop and have a table like this:

```
ID  Parent_ID   R_ID    Action  
01  0           0       CC
02  0           0       Dev
03  0           0       Com
04  0           0       CC
05  02          0       Cap
06  05          02      Check
07  0           0       CC
08  03          0       Cap
09  0           0       CC
10  08          03      Check
11  0           0       Dev         
12  0           0       Com
```

And I want to create a calculated field to add a new column `Check` which for each `Dev` or `Com` that has a `Check` add Yes and No.

```
ID  Parent_ID   R_ID    Action      Check
01  0           0       CC          No
02  0           0       Dev         Yes
03  0           0       Com         Yes
04  0           0       CC          No
05  02          0       Cap         No
06  05          02      Check       No
07  0           0       CC          No
08  03          0       Cap         No
09  0           0       CC          No
10  08          03      Check       No  
11  0           0       Dev         No
12  0           0       Com         No
```

I tried a lot with `If` but I didn't get a satisfied result.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: `if [Action] = "Dev" then "Yes" elseif [Action] = "Com" then "Yes" else "No" end`, or something along those lines?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, but this code add `Yes` for 11 and 12 item even they don't have a check and I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify which column named 'check'  you are referring to

> add a new column Check which for each Dev or Com that has a
>   ***Check*** add Yes and No

Comment: The fifth column in my table @Kalidas

Comment: If ([Action] = "Dev" or  [Action] = "Com" ) and [Check] = "Yes" Then "Yes" else "No" End